# Make the script works if only cell content specific value

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to make the VB script check all the cells and color it if it has the specific value
Ex: "1" shade it Green not 12 or text with number

```
Sub CheckTableCellContent()
    Dim tbl As table
    Dim row As row
    Dim cell As cell
    
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each row In tbl.Rows
            For Each cell In row.Cells
                If cell.Range.Text Like "*1*" Then
                    cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
               ElseIf cell.Range.Text Like "*2*" Then
                    cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(146, 208, 80)
               ElseIf cell.Range.Text Like "*3*" Then
                    cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
             ElseIf cell.Range.Text Like "*4*" Then
                    cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    
        
                End If
            Next cell
        Next row
    Next tbl
    
End Sub
```

it colors any cell has 1 not Only 1 and the same with the rest

Comment: This is not VBScript it’s MS Word VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*1*` pattern (see [Like Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator)) will match any string that has 1 in it. Both `abc1def` and `21` will match and from your question, that doesn't sound like what you are trying to do.

In order to color the cells that only have `1` in them, you would use "1" as your pattern:

```
cell.Range.Text Like "1"
```

When I tested this I noticed that there were other characters in the cell text so I modified the code to take those out before checking the value:

```
Sub CheckTableCellContent()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim row As row
    Dim cell As cell
    Dim cellText As String
    
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        
        For Each row In tbl.Rows
            
            For Each cell In row.Cells
                
                cellText = cell.Range.Text
                cellText = Replace(cellText, Chr(13), "")
                cellText = Replace(cellText, Chr(7), "")
                
                Select Case cellText
                    Case "1"
                        cell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                    Case "2"
                        cell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(146, 208, 80)
                    Case "3"
                        cell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    Case "4"
                        cell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End Select
            
            Next cell
        
        Next row
    
    Next tbl
    
End Sub
```